# Referencing Assets in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm helping a colleague configure a new box for an existing Drupal install with multiple sites. It's functioning, but I've noticed that all assets are being referenced as `/sites/<site-name>/files/image.png`. I don't know from Drupal, but it strikes me that Drupal should be abstracting the logical site from the code so that site-specific assets could be referenced as `/files/image.png` and Drupal would figure out -- perhaps based on `HTTP_HOST` -- which site is meant.

In this case, we need separate snapshots of the same site (dev and staging) so we'd like to be able to store the paths without specifically referencing one site or the other. We can do some rewriting to manage this, but I'm wondering whether there's something that we simply don't know.

Does Drupal do this natively in some way? If not, what are others doing to manage this kind of abstraction? Surely we're not the first to encounter this and think there must be a better way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be an interesting module. The Files directory can be in the following locations:

```
sites/<site name>/files (standard for multi sites, public)
```

or

```
sites/default/files (standard installation for single sites, public)
```

That is, if you want to use the public files method.

Read here if you want to learn about the private files method (very similar to your thought): http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/file

Comment: This is a multi-site install, so I'm assuming that sites/default/files isn't standard for that...right?

Comment: Right, since Drupal 5 (current is 7), you've been able to create sites that share the base Drupal installation (every folders besides the sites/ folder) and then each domain could have it's own sites folder.

A change in the Drupal 7 spec is that all files are actually internally called using schemas, like "public://folder/file.png" and it translates into "sites/<site name>/folder/file.png" or whatever is needed.

Comment: So is it relatively standard, then, for folks to load theme images as `/sites/<site>/themes/<my-theme>/images/image-name.gif`? Likewise, to link images as `/sites/<site>/files/image-name.png`? Remembering, of course, that this is Drupal 6.